# Grab value from Array JS vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, jsx

Could anyone point me in the right direction where i can read about the solution. It works fine in console and lost for ideas at this point.

```
Promise.all([
    DishSource.getDishDetails(523145),
    DishSource.getDishDetails(787321),
    DishSource.getDishDetails(452179),
]).then((values) =>
    Vue.render(
        <SidebarView guests={5} dishes={values} />,
        document.getElementById("app")
    )
);
```

**SidebarView :**

```
<table>
    {props.dishes.values.map((e) => (
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button> x </button>
            </td>
            <td>{e.title}</td>
            <td>{e.dishType}</td>
            <td>{e.dishPrice}</td>
        </tr>
    ))}
</table>
```

[image: Error msg + console logs]

Answer (score 1):

At the first rendering `dishes` property is not available, so you should add some conditional rendering :

```
{props.dishes && props.dishes.values.map(e => ...
```

Comment: Should it not wait for the promises to be fulfilled befor it tries to render, if i set the condition it dosnot render at all. Since Vue render is in the "then" statement.

Comment: it should render that when the data is available, please share an example in codesanbox